# How to print my return statement

Tags: java, arrays, printing

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static int searchItems (){
    String searchTerm = "";
    int pos = -1;
    String [] listToSearch = {"apple", "pear", "orange", "kiwi"};

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter your search: ");
    searchTerm = in.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < listToSearch.length; i++){
        if (listToSearch[i].equals(searchTerm)){
            return i;               
        }   

    }
        return pos;

}
```

I don't run into any issues with this method, but I have to somehow print out either the position that the word the user entered is in, or if the word entered is not in the array to print -1 to the command line.

I'm pretty sure I need a print statement but everywhere I have tried I can't get anything to work...

Comment: Go through the official tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the return statement, call your `searchItems()` method inside your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print(searchItems());
}

public static int searchItems (){
    ....
}
```